# How to use TCPlink in Using unreal Game Engine to connect to MYSQL?

Tags: game-engine, unreal-development-kit, unreal-engine4

I am using to unreal game engine to develop my new game and I need to connect to my MySQL database (probably using PHP) from my game to store and retrieve data. I check on the internet but couldn't find how to use TCPlink in code. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably get better answers on [Unreal Engine Questions](https://answers.unrealengine.com/) or [the foums](https://forums.unrealengine.com)